# CSS menu moving on hover

Tags: css, navigation, hover

The code I was trying is moderate I thought, but in case of hovering on the menu the menu is moving both with the text and the background. I have tried a couple of codes that I found here but that didn't make any change. The code is -

**HTML :**

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
    div.nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 50px -120px;
}

div.nav ul{
    display: block;
    width: 480px;
}

div.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.nav ul li a:link, div.nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #1E1E1C;
    font-family: RockwellRegular,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #e41f4c;
    border: 10px solid #e41f4c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Can't find any solutions yet!

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/shuvo_nasir/T7Kud/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/T7Kud/1/

Apply the border size to the `a`tags and make the border color transparent, on hover, just change the border color.

```
div.nav ul li a:link, div.nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #1E1E1C;
    font-family: RockwellRegular,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
div.nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #e41f4c;
    border-color: #e41f4c;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Man you are awesome!!! I was tried to solve this from last night, but coding it in your way worked just withing a couple of seconds! Thanks Arbel.

Comment: @shuvonasir You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you. You can select my answer as the answer for future references.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonje/8fc3A/ . I have removed the padding from li and added padding in a tag as this is the right way to add hover if there is padding.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 50px -120px;
}

div.nav ul {
    display: block;
    width: 480px;
}

div.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.nav ul li a:link, div.nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #1E1E1C;
    font-family: RockwellRegular,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

div.nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #e41f4c;
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.nav {
float: right;
margin: 50px -120px;
}

div.nav ul{
display: block;
width: 480px;
}

div.nav ul li {
float: left;

list-style-type: none;
} 
div.nav ul li a {
padding: 10px 10px;
} 

div.nav ul li a:link, div.nav ul li a:visited {
color: #1E1E1C;
font-family: RockwellRegular,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}
div.nav ul li a:hover{
background: #e41f4c;
/*  border: 10px solid #e41f4c;*/
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZP6us/)**

Answer (score 0):

You've got a border on the link hover but not on the normal state.  This changes the width and height.
I recommend setting a border on the link normal state with border color of your page background so it's not visible, eg:

```
div.nav ul li a:link, div.nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #1E1E1C;
    font-family: RockwellRegular,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a width for li element 
It will resolove you problem .
You have increased border which in turn increase the size of li elements

```
div.nav ul li {
float: left;
padding: 0 10px;
list-style-type: none;
```

width :100 px;
    }

http://jsfiddle.net/T7Kud/4/